Why did NASDAQ show an inaccurate stock price history after the split?
I checked all sources, including Google Finance, Yahoo Finance, and even NASDAQ. They displayed an inaccurate price when compared with the information on the company's own website.
For example, Nvidia's closing price is listed as $132.91 on the company's website, but all other sources showed it traded at $13.29.
You can see this in a Google Sheet with the formula =GOOGLEFINANCE("NVDA","price","03/16/2021").
Even after accounting for the stock splits that occurred twice since 2021, resulting in a 1:40 split, the prices still do not match. Any idea why?

It looks like the NVDA own website is not adjusted for their recent 1:10 split. You can see the closing prices reported on their website drop from 1200ish to 120ish after 06/10/2024 which is the last split date. They seem to have adjusted for the 2021 4:1 split though.

Yes. It is unadjusted price. If you take that price and divided by 40, it still does not match the price shown on google, yahoo or nasdaq. That just made my OCD go nut, cant figure this out.

@laughing it's adjusted for the 1:4 split in 2021, but not for the 1:10 split in 2024. So divide by 10.

oh that would make sense, 132.91/10, that gave me a match with the price shown on all other sources. Thanks. Now I can sleep.
